# How to edit a SharePoint WebPart backend code

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development, web-part

I am not a SharePoint Developer but I have a background in programming. And now, can someone please help me on how to edit a SharePoint Web Part? I am using SharePoint designer and what I can only see is the line of code similar to this:

```
<WebPartPages:SPUserCodeProperty Name="MyMetricChoice" Value="Corporate-EBITDA">
</WebPartPages:SPUserCodeProperty>
</Properties>
</WebPartPages:SPUserCodeWebPart>
```

I have to get into its codes so I can change the output in our page.

Comment: Jen-
Can you be more specific about which webpart you added to the page. Also most of web parts will be configurable like changing the properties.

Comment: Which web part you want to edit? Which functionality you want to achieve? Can you please provide more description in question.

Comment: I think the webpart is customized. And it is customized by a third party group. The output really is a graph, so they wanted to remove 2015 months and start with Jan 2016. That is why I am asking where can I see the code behind of webParts so I can change it. It is not something I can edit with properties

Comment: When I open it in SharePoint designer this is how it looks like:  
<WebPartPages:SPUserCodeProperty Name="MyMetricChoice" Value="Corporate-Turnover"></WebPartPages:SPUserCodeProperty>
</Properties>
</WebPartPages:SPUserCodeWebPart>

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a code than its almost impossible to change the code behind of your webpart. Even if you extract the WSP in Visual studio than you will not able to get code behind files of your webpart's UserControls.

The most important thing in SharePoint development is, you need administrative rights to deploy any of the solution in SharePoint.

If changing the code behind is possible without the source code than it will be drawback of the SharePoint (It means anyone can change anybody's site if have access to it).

So kindly don't waste your time. Please contact the SharePoint Administrator.

Comment: Thanks Hardik for the advise. I am an administrator and have access to the site. But I am not familiar with the deployment or creating/editing the webpart. Can you advise where can I see it and I will try to open. If not I will contact my colleague who has more powers than me. Thanks!

Comment: You are a site administrator not SharePoint Administrator. You can't do it without a source code as you want to change the code behind. If you want to do some design change than you can do it using SharePoint designer. But code behind change is not possible

Comment: If you feel my answer have useful information than please mark it. so others can get benefit of this information. Thanks

Comment: I get your point, thanks. But if they give me access can I change the webpart code? Can you advise how?

Comment: If you do have a webpart code & if you let know about the webpart changes than i will surely help you on this. It will be my pleasure to help you.